# What's a cogniteme?

Tags: terminology, cognitive-linguistics

Today, I encountered for the first time the term *cogniteme*. What is it meaning and history?

A quick search shows that the term is used by Kyrgyz, Ukrainian, and Russian authors and it may be an ad hoc translation from Russian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *cogniteme* is formed similarly to such words as *grapheme*, *morpheme* etc. Some googling gave no results for the English spelling, but a few for the corresponging Russian *когнитема*.

Here is the definition given in [the abstract of the doctoral thesis](https://static.freereferats.ru/_avtoreferats/01002627269.pdf) of E. V. Ivanova from Saint Petersburg State University:

> [...] когнитема -­ пропозициональная единица знания, меньшая, чем пословица. Когнитемы образуют когнитивную модель пословицы, когнитивные структуры, соотнесенные с различными по объему группами пословиц, пословичные концепты и прототипы.
>
> cogniteme is a prepositional unit of knowledge smaller than a proverb. Cognitemes form a cognitive model of a proverb, cognitive structures associated with variously sized groups of proverbs, proverbial concepts and prototypes.

The topic of the thesis is "Proverbial conceptualization of the world (on the material of English and Russian proverbs)".

There are [some](https://nsu.ru/xmlui/bitstream/handle/nsu/6269/26.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) [other](http://izvestia.vspu.ru/files/publics/90/20-23.pdf) Russian-language studies in the field of cognitive linguistics which use the term *cogniteme*. All of them have references to works of E. V. Ivanova, so I think it can be assumed that she is the author of the term.

Comment: So щи да каша and пища наша would be (rhyming) cognitemes?